# Can a read to a raw socket return multiple packets at once?

Tags: c++, sockets, boost

When reading a raw socket, does it always return exactly 0 or 1 packets?

More specifically, is that the case with:

1. linux/win32 user space API?
2. [boost::asio basic_raw_socket.async_receive()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_raw_socket/async_receive/overload1.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boost `basic_raw_socket::async_receive` does not support receiving raw sockets, it only works with connected sockets, and one cannot connect to raw sockets -- you would need `basic_raw_socket::async_receive_from` for that. This function *explicitly* supports receiving into several buffers, so you have no guarantee that you will only ever get zero or one datagrams at a time.

Note that there is no strict guarantee that you will (or can) receive multiple datagrams at a time, however. This is something explicitly *allowed* by the library's API (since you can supply several buffers), but it says nowhere that the library is *required* to actually use them all. It's therefore technically possible for the library to always only return a single datagram, even if you supply several buffers. If you get several datagrams in "one" async receive operation, this may be simulated by several read operations on the OS layer (unless the operating system supports scatter/gather I/O on sockets and this is implemented in your Boost version for your platform).

On the socket layer, "raw" implies a datagram socket (there is *no such thing* as a raw stream socket!), and reads on datagram sockets *always*<sup>1</sup> return one complete datagram (or part of it, if the supplied buffer is too small, in this case the rest is thrown away) or an error. This behaviour is identical on Linux and Windows and every other platform, assuming a non-broken implementation.
Note that you'll usually need administrative privilegues to send and receive on raw sockets, and in the case of Windows, you'll need an early, non-patched Windows XP, or a server version (raw sockets are otherwise disabled to prevent address spoofing, forged TCP resets, and other attacks).

To clarify on the above: a raw socket will receive "network layer" (level 3) datagrams. Even if those packets really belong to a TCP stream or are UDP packets, for your raw socket they are still only IP packets. As such, they have no port number (they do, but as payload, not as part of the header), and there is nothing to connect to, and no other information such as e.g. a sequence number to pinpoint the packet's position in a stream. Thus, no such thing as a non-packet raw socket can exist, and there's nothing you could connect to.

---

<sup>1</sup>Scatter/gather exempted

Comment: It can only be used with *connected* sockets according to the documentation. There is no such thing as 'bind *to* a socket'.

Comment: Why would async_receive not work with raw_sockets? I've used it for over 2 years without any problem.

Comment: @KilianDS: `async_receive` (without `from`) presumes a connected socket. What do you connect to on a raw socket? There's no stream to connect to, not even a port number, in a raw IP datagram.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a datagram socket (for example: a raw packet socket, or a UDP socket), then you'll get exactly 0 (nothing) or 1 packet.

If you use a connection-oriented socket (for example: a TCP socket), then the number of messages you can get out of any API does not have any mandatory relation to the number of actual packets received.